# Pyspark - Count zero value columns between each pair of non-zero value columns

Tags: pyspark, distance

Let's say we have this table (first row is the title)

[image: sample table]

How can I count the number of zero value cells between two non-zero value cells?
For example, the output for the above table should be a list of (3,2)

Panda interrow and cell counting may work but it is clearly not efficient for big dataset. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following series of transformations.

I have added some more data to test boundary cases.

To see the output up to a particular step, just comment all steps that follow:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
   [
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
      [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
      [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
      [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]
    ],
   [str(i) for i in range(0,11)]
)

df.select(F.array(df.columns).alias("c")) \
  .select(F.array_join("c", delimiter="").alias("c")) \
  .select(F.regexp_replace("c", r"^0*", "").alias("c")) \
  .select(F.regexp_replace("c", r"0*$", "").alias("c")) \
  .select(F.split("c", "1").alias("c")) \
  .select(F.transform("c", lambda s: F.length(s)).alias("c")) \
  .select(F.filter("c", lambda i: i > 0).alias("c")) \
  .show(truncate=False)

[Out]:
+---------------+
|c              |
+---------------+
|[]             |
|[]             |
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]|
|[1, 1, 1, 1]   |
|[3, 2]         |
+---------------+
```

Comment: @TomNguyen, did this solution work for you?